# parsererror and Unexpected token < in JSON at position in ajax and django?

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

please look into below code

AJAX FUNCTION

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#id_module").on('change', function(){
  var mod1 = $(this).val();
  alert(mod1);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'submodule/'+ mod1,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        submod=response['submod'];
        alert(submod);
        $('#submodule').empty();
        $("#submodule").prepend($('<option>',
            {
                value: '',
                text: '-- Select Sub Module Type --'
            }));
        $.each(submod, function(ind){
        $("#submodule").append($('<option>',
            {
                value: submod[ind]['sub_module'],
                text: submod[ind]['sub_module']
            }));
            });
        $('#submodule').selectpicker("refresh");
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

My Django -- URL:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from E_Ticketing import views

urlpatterns = [re_path(r'^eForm/report$',views.reports{'template_name':'reports.html'},name='report'),re_path(r'^eForm/resolution$',views.resolutionForm{'template_name':'Resolution_Form.html'},name='resolution'),
re_path(r'^eForm/assign$',views.assignForm,{'template_name':'assign_form.html'},name='assign'),
re_path(r'^eForm',views.eticket, {'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),
re_path(r'^eForm/submodule/(?P<n_moduleid>\d+)$',views.submodule,name='submodule'),
re_path(r'^eForm/fillemp/(?P<n_empid>\d+)$',views.fillemp,name='fillemp'),
 ]
 if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My Django --Views:

```
def submodule(request,n_moduleid):
try:
    if request.method=='GET':
        submod=[]
        submod=TblTxEticketdetails.objects.using('ETicketing').values('sub_module').filter(Q(module_id=n_moduleid)).distinct()
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error Occurred!!!')
    data = {'submod': list(submod)}
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    messages.error(request, "Error Occured!!!")
```

This is my first time pasting question in stack overflow.I think i have messed up posting my question. please fell free to ask questions regarding code

i have gone through all of my code and i couldn't find where my code is wrong. while running, alert box appears but it does not go to ajax function. i need little help please!!!

i am getting error in this way

```
text status: parsererror
eForm:1676 error: SyntaxError:Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it is not going in to ajax....i tried keeping alert box in ajax but not working

Comment: try this `url: 'submodule/'+ mod1+'/',` in the ajax url

Comment: still not working.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace and also the full urls.py file?

Comment: What you mean, not working ?

Comment: Browser sends data on server ? what response is coming from server ? (Make monitoring with browser).

Comment: i have added my full url.py file.

Comment: it's not going to views.py submodule function

Comment: What response browser returns ?

Comment: it is returning nothing

Comment: there are 2 ajax functions in similar way in web page.. both are not working

Comment: What it means nothing ? ```200```, ```404```, ```500``` ?

Please, ```return JsonResponse()``` in ```try``` as well as in ```except```.

Comment: also, add ```error: function(jqXHR) {console.log('error');}``` in ```ajax```. after ```success()```.

Comment: showing error undefined

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Check "Network" tab in Chrome, look into response http status and response body. I guess it is HTML, not  JSON. In `except` part you are not returning JSON!

Comment: is it in django views....now i have added still it's showing html in response@IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys,

I found the answer,

in url.py I have changed

```
re_path(r'^eForm',views.eticket{'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),
```

to

```
re_path(r'^eForm$',views.eticket,{'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),
```

after '^eForm' have to add '$' while excetuting ajax, it is going to other views. so i am not getting the correct answer

Thanks guys for responding to my question:)