# Ajax getting error parse error and Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

please look into below code

AJAX FUNCTION

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#id_module").on('change', function(){
  var mod1 = $(this).val();
  alert(mod1);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'submodule/'+ mod1,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        submod=response['submod'];
        alert(submod);
        $('#submodule').empty();
        $("#submodule").prepend($('<option>',
            {
                value: '',
                text: '-- Select Sub Module Type --'
            }));
        $.each(submod, function(ind){
        $("#submodule").append($('<option>',
            {
                value: submod[ind]['sub_module'],
                text: submod[ind]['sub_module']
            }));
            });
        $('#submodule').selectpicker("refresh");
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

My Django -- URL:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from E_Ticketing import views

urlpatterns = [re_path(r'^eForm/report$',views.reports{'template_name':'reports.html'},name='report'),re_path(r'^eForm/resolution$',views.resolutionForm{'template_name':'Resolution_Form.html'},name='resolution'),
re_path(r'^eForm/assign$',views.assignForm,{'template_name':'assign_form.html'},name='assign'),
re_path(r'^eForm',views.eticket, {'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),
re_path(r'^eForm/submodule/(?P<n_moduleid>\d+)$',views.submodule,name='submodule'),
re_path(r'^eForm/fillemp/(?P<n_empid>\d+)$',views.fillemp,name='fillemp'),
 ]
 if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My Django --Views:

```
def submodule(request,n_moduleid):
try:
    if request.method=='GET':
        submod=[]
        submod=TblTxEticketdetails.objects.using('ETicketing').values('sub_module').filter(Q(module_id=n_moduleid)).distinct()
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error Occurred!!!')
    data = {'submod': list(submod)}
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    messages.error(request, "Error Occured!!!")
```

i have gone through all of my code and i couldn't find where my code is wrong. while running, alert box appears but it does not go to ajax function. i need little help please!!!

i am getting error in this way

```
text status: parsererror
eForm:1676 error: SyntaxError:Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Have to try using the google devTools. You can have a look at what results are getting send back there might be a issue with the response that is getting send back. Here is an example on how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsererror and Unexpected token < in JSON at position in ajax and django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422147/parsererror-and-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-in-ajax-and-django)

Comment: yes...i didn't get answer..so i posted again.....

Comment: @AndreHoffmann..... initiating ajax call....return content is not visible

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't be catching all exceptions like that. Let Django tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: i kept a break point at my django views.py ....but its not going to views.py file

Comment: i kept a break point at my django views.py ....but its not going to views.py file @DanielRoseman

Comment: remove `try ... except` as @DanielRoseman says. that way you'll see the exception in your django console.

Comment: error is same as mentioned above after removing try and except

Comment: in response, html code is there. what to do to get json response?@dirkgroten and @DanielRoseman

Comment: If it's not going to your view, where is it going? What do the browser dev tools show?

Comment: showing some html code which i have written

Comment: dev tools in network>Xhr it is showing some html code which i have written @DanielRoseman

Comment: Oh come on that isn't what I asked at all. Where is the request going? Exactly what response does it show?

Comment: really....i have written nearly 2000 lines of html code.....in response, i am seeing all the code i have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys,

I found the answer,

in url.py
I have changed
 re_path(r'^eForm',views.eticket{'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),

to
   re_path(r'^eForm$',views.eticket,{'template_name':'e_ticket_form.html'},name='eticket'),

after '^eForm' 
have to add '$' 
while excetuting ajax, it is going to other views. so i am not getting the correct answer

Thanks guys for responding to my question:)